Object specific quick action without modal pop up

when i click the cancel button the LWC pop will be removed but quick action pop up not removed,I have included the screenshots for your refrence 

does the cancel button onclick function call this.close(); ? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-modal/documentation

The screen pop up was successfully removed but default quick action pop up was not removed
